# IOS handle event click button in tableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

In my cell have 1 button.

I want to change button title when I click.

Exp: default title: Play

When I click button the first it will handle event1, and change title to Stop.

When I click the second, it will change title to Play and handle event2.

...

Understand me? And remember that: button in tableView Cell.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Here is Objective-C version:

```
- (void) playPauseAction:(id)sender {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    if ([button.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"Play"]) {
        [button setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // Playing code
    } else {
        [button setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // Pausing code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
   UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:Your Frame];
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   Button.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Button];
```

Then write `ButtonClicked` method

```
-(void)ButtonClicked:(UIButton*)button{
      if (button.tag == 0)
      {
             //Here button at 0th row is selected.
            //Write your code here
      }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1) In your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, assign button tag as index:

```
cell.yourbutton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

2) Add target and action for your button as below:

```
[cell.yourbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

3) Code actions based on index as below in ViewControler:

```
-(void)yourButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
     Bool cicked=1;
     if(clicked)
     {
       [cell.yourbutton setTitle: @"myTitle" forState:@""]; 
     }

}
```

Comment: No! Change title button and change handle event click button.

Comment: In addition to the above solution, you can configure the button for label text for different button states  and on button click selector, just toggle the state of the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try these way......


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
            tags = (int)indexPath.row;
            [tblname reloadData];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier"
    ............
    ............
    ............
    if (indexpath.row == tags){
       [cell.btnName setTitle:@"Newtitle" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}else{
          [cell.btnName setTitle:@"OldTitle" forState:UIControlStateNoramal];
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Add TargetAction to the button as

```
 [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

2.Just follow action method like this

```
    -(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)btn
    {
        if ([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Play"]) {
            [btn setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else{
             [btn setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
```